# Formatting data for Google Charts

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am trying to achieve something in order to get my data formatted correctly for Google Charts.  At the moment, I have data in the following format

```
Array(4)
    0: {Category: "cat2", Count: 11}
    1: {Category: "cat4", Count: 24}
    2: {Category: "cat3", Count: 52}
    3: {Category: "cat1", Count: 57}
```

Google requires the first row to be the Labels, and the other rows the content.  So in my case Google requires my data to be like so

```
let data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
   ['Category', 'Count'],
   ['cat1',  11],
   ['cat2',  24],
   ['cat3',  52],
   ['cat4',  57]
]);
```

In order to do this, I am doing the following

```
generateData (data) {
    return [Object.keys(data[0])].
    concat(
        data.map(
            data => Object.values(data)
        )
    );
}
```

So this all works fine, however, there are two additional things I am trying to achieve.  Firstly, I want to make sure the data is in a particular order.

So this is what I am thinking, I do not need to dynamically collect the categories like I do above.  Reason for this is because I know it will always be 4 categories, cat1, cat2, cat3 and cat4. So I could potentially define my categories, in the order I want them.

```
generateData (data) {
    let myArray = [];
    const header = ["Category", "Count"];
    const categories = ["cat1", "cat2", "cat3", "cat4"];
    myArray.push(header);
}
```

But then how do I add the additional rows from the data array, making sure it matches up with the correct category?

The second thing I wan to do is give each categories bar its own color.  According to the Google docs, within the header row, I can add a style

```
let myArray = [];
const header = ["Category", "Count", { role: 'style' }];
const categories = ["cat1", "cat2", "cat3", "cat4"];
const colors = ["red", "blue", "silver", "yellow"];
myArray.push(header);
```

But then for the additional rows, from my data array, I would need to add the appropiate color for each category.  So the final array I am after should look something like this

```
[
  ["category", "Count", { role: 'style' }],
  ["cat1", "11", "red"],
  ["cat2", "24", "blue"],
  ["cat3", "52", "silver"],
  ["cat4", "57", "yellow"]
];
```

How can I achieve this with the initial data that is being passed?

Thanks

Comment: Why you don't have array of count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `forEach` on any of the the arrays and then create an array with three values with corresponding values.

```js
let myArray = [];
const header = ["Category", "Count", { role: 'style' }];
const data = [
   {"Category":"cat3","Count":59},
   {"Category":"cat1","Count":109},
   {"Category":"cat2","Count":120},
   {"Category":"cat4","Count":57}
]
const obj = data.reduce((ac,{Category, Count}) => (ac[Category] = Count,ac),{});
const categories = ["cat1", "cat2", "cat3", "cat4"];
const count = [57, 11, 52, 24];
const colors = ["red", "blue", "silver", "yellow"];
myArray.push(header);
categories.forEach((x,i) => {
  myArray.push([x,obj[x],colors[i]]);
})
console.log(myArray)
```

Comment: Not quite working.  The count is contained within the data array I am passing the function, alongside the category.  I need to match the category from this array to my categories array, and then extract the count

Comment: @kate_hudson I have updated the answer please check it.

Comment: Sorry about the duplicate, thought I reworded the above bad.  Thanks, works perfectly